# TS 2322 in some HttpClient services after upgrading angular 5.2 to 6.0.7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm mid-way through an update to Angular 6 with TypeScript ~2.7.0. In Angular 5.2.12, I wrote service methods like this:

```
isPartDraft = (part: number): Observable<boolean> =>
  this._http.get(`${this.rest}/isDraft/${part}`)
            .catch(MyPartService.handleError);
```

annotating the function definition with a return type, but without asserting its type within the function body.

It seems that is no longer possible *in some contexts*, as `tsc` raises:

```
TS2322:
Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

and I'm forced to assert the return type within the function body as recommended in the [current Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response):

```
isPartDraft = (part: number) =>
  this._http.get<boolean>(`${this.rest}/isDraft/${part}`)
      .pipe(catchError(MyService.handleError));
```

So far so good (we never changed our annotations since angular2-rc6, so this might have been lurking for a while).

But in **these** cases I don't get any TS error:

```
getPasswordPolicy(): Observable<PasswordPolicy> {
  return this._http.get(`${this.rest}/securityPolicy/`)
    .pipe(
      map((securityPolicy: any) => securityPolicy.passwordPolicy),
      catchError(error => observableThrowError(error))
    );
}
```

And in a different service:

```
getPartsAtDate = (id: number, date: string, time: string): Observable<number[]> =>
  this._http.get(`${this.rest}/partsOnDate/${id}/${date}/${time}`)
    .pipe(catchError(MyService.handleError));

getAllNewOrders = (id: number): Observable<Orders[]> =>
  this._http.get(`${this.rest}/${id}`)
    .pipe(catchError(MyService.handleError));
```

So how do the `pipe()`, `catchError()` and `map()` operators interact to produce this situation? Why can't I annotate the function definition in the first case but can in the second three?

(Of course I could robotically fix the places tsc throws errors, but I'd much rather understand what's going on, especially as identical contexts seem to produce different results.)

As requested, here is the error handler (the implementation is identical in each service):

```
private static handleError(error: any) {
  console.log('error ' + error);
  return observableThrowError(error.status || 'Server error');
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `MyService.handleError`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks! Just added it.

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: The first one is easy to explain: this._http.get() returns an Observable<Object>, but you map it using a function that accepts any as argument. An Object is an any, so that's valid, and your function returns securityPolicy.passwordPolicy, which is a PasswordPolicy, so you indeed get an Observable<PasswordPolicy>. The second one, assuming observableThrowError is in fact throwError, does cause an error here, as I expect (using TS 2.7.2)

Comment: I'm a bit confused; do `getPartsAtDate` and `getAllNewOrders` cause errors or not?

Comment: @ExplosionPills The first version of `isPartDraft` causes an error, *all* the other code blocks compile successfully. I added those because they seem, to me, to be basically identical from a type-checking perspective. I didn't understand why that pattern caused errors in one context but not in another. I also added typescript ~2.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get` is overloaded and not all versions use Generics. Based on how you call `get` in your first example the signature that is chosen is the one that returns `Observable<Object>`. If you want another kind of observable you have to use generics (like `get<boolean>`).

Why do the other examples work?

```
map((securityPolicy: any) => securityPolicy.passwordPolicy),
```

Here, you explicitly change the type from `Observable<Object>` to `Observable< PasswordPolicy>`. It wouldn't work if you had `map((securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy`.

`catchError` doesn't change the type of the observable like `map` does in your case. So it's still `Observable<Object>`.

Comment: Ah, digging a bit in `@angular/common/http/HttpClient#get` I see the overloads and why type annotation is placed where it is. But given this, why does `getPartsAtDate` *not* raise an error, as it seems identical to the first version of `isPartDraft`?

Comment: I've never had much success trying to make faithful MCVE with Angular applications. There must be some subtle difference between my example and my actual implementation. Thanks, I'll chalk it up to that.